# How to raise a global event in dojo?

Tags: events, event-handling, dojo, dom-events

I am trying to raise an event to all of the widgets that catch it.  I have an authentication widget and other widgets that depend on the fact that the user is logged in.  I would like to raise an event to all of those widgets when a user is logged in without connecting them manually. How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [dojo.publish](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.4/dojo.publish) and [dojo.subscribe](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.4/dojo.subscribe)

Perhaps this is a [better link](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/publish)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some more detailed and up-to-date links on pub/sub in Dojo:

**Blog posts**
http://davidwalsh.name/dojo-pub-sub
http://startdojo.com/2010/05/21/decoupling-widget-to-widget-interaction-with-dojo/
http://www.naelshawwa.com/dojo-how-to-publish-subscribe-2/

**Docs**
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/publish.html
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/subscribe.html
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/events.html (particularly the last section)

Once your javascript web app gets at all complicated, pub/sub is a godsend, allowing you to decouple your classes, and so make your code more maintainable and modular.

Answer (score 1):

```
dojo.subscribe("mytopic",console,"debug");
dojo.publish("mytopic",["whatever"]);
```